# About symbolic MATLAB

Tags: matlab, fluid-dynamics

What is wrong with the following code?

```
clear all

syms x y a ;

u=2*x*y;
v=a^2+x^2-y^2;

diff=diff(u,'x',1)+diff(v,'y',1);
if diff==0
    disp('Liquid motion is possible.')
    disp('Stream function exists.')
else
    disp('Liquid motion is not possible.')
    disp('Stream function does not exist.')
end

diff2=diff(v,'x',1)-diff(u,'y',1);
if diff2==0
    disp('Velocity potential exists.')
else
    disp('Velocity potential does not exist.')
end
```

This comes in the command window when I run the above.

```
Liquid motion is possible.
Stream function exists.
Error using sym/subsindex (line 672)
Invalid indexing or function definition. When defining a function, ensure that the body of the function is a SYM
object. When indexing, the input must be numeric, logical or ':'.

Error in sym>privformat (line 1502)
    x = subsindex(x)+1;

Error in sym/subsref (line 694)
            [inds{k},refs{k}] = privformat(inds{k});

Error in q7 (line 17)
diff2=diff(v,'x',1)-diff(u,'y',1);
```

But if I rewrite(redefine) the symbolic variables after the first `if` construct, it runs fine. Also if I cancel the first `if` construct, it runs.

Comment: Don’t redefine the built-in function `diff`. And use [`isAlways`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/isalways.html) instead of `==` for symbolic comparisons. `diff(u,’x’,1)` is the same as `diff(u,x)`.

Comment: To expand on @horchler's comment, you are creating a new variable called `diff` which shadows the builtin `diff` function. In general you need to avoid naming variables with the same names as functions you want to use.

Comment: @horchler Thanks. Solved my problem.

Comment: @horchler Using `isAlways` instead of `==` is giving me the `else` answer in `if` construct, which is incorrect here. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid to overwrite a reserved name, so instead of

```
diff=diff(u,'x',1)+diff(v,'y',1);
```

I would suggest

```
derFcn = diff(u,'x',1)+diff(v,'y',1);
```

This triggers the second error;

```
diff2=diff(v,'x',1)-diff(u,'y',1);
```

at this point diff is your diff  value (which, incidentally is 0) so it is equivalent to write

```
0(v,'x',1)
```

which, of course, will not compile and it is not what you meant.

So, please, make the substitution (and update your if statements accordingly).

Comment: Sorry I read the other responses only after posting mine. I think they should be posted as answers. Also, it is true that diff == 0 is not correct, as you are comparing a symbolic expression.

Comment: Using isAlways instead of == is giving me the else answer in if construct, which is incorrect here. Any idea why?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts. Every post ends with your user card and a link to your profile already, signatures or taglines in posts are considered noise and they will be removed.